# Using futures from a function block in node-RED

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am using node RED for a  project and got stuck trying to use a function that returns a future when called.

I just want to confirm if futures work from function blocks? Below is the code I tried:

```
var Influx = context.global.influx;

const hist = new Influx.InfluxDB({
    host:'external.server',
    port:8086,
    username:'user',
    password:'password',
    database: 'histories',
});

hist.getMeasurements().then(names => {
    node.send({payload:names});
});

return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, promises should work just fine.

You don't seam to have any error handling, so if there is a problem it will just be ignored. Add a `.catch()` to the promise chain to handle errors.

Also any reason why you're not using the influxdb node? http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-influxdb